# Licensing (Bash) scripts under the GPL?

Tags: licensing

I've written some bash scripts (< 200 lines of code each) I wanna share with the world, but as I'm a FLOSS fan my first thought was to share them under the terms of the GPL.

But...is that nonsense? I mean, I understand why to share a whole application under the terms of the GPL, but does it make sense for such small scripts? Or would it be the best thing to share them as Public Domain, since they're nothing really special or fancy? Or is there any special kind of licensing 'treatment' for scripts out there?

I'd really appreciate some opinions on this matter, and thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Thanks to everyone for the answers...I wish I could accept more than one, because they all answered my question altogether!

Comment: Gentoo ebuilds are just bash scripts, and are GPLed.

Comment: Hi, this is also answered in the FAQ: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatIfWorkIsShort

Comment: Voting to close because it's off-topic (shame on me): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70444/are-licensing-questions-on-or-off-topic-on-so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share anything under the GPL. "Hello World", even. It's a philosophical choice. If you don't mind someone taking these small scripts and redistributing them as closed source, make 'em public domain. If you do mind, make them GPL or something similar.

Comment: You can't actually put Hello World under the GPL. It's not original, and therefore not eligible for copyright protection. Without copyright, you can't license it, not even under the GPL.

Comment: @MSalters: at least in the EU, computer programs are exempt from the originality requirement. Now, trying to prove in court that *your* hello world is a derivative of *my* hello world is another matter entirely ...

Comment: @Jorg: No, you're wrong. "A computer program shall be protected if it is original ... " (from Council Directive 91/250/EEC of 14 May 1991 on the legal protection of computer programs, Article 1)

Comment: @MSalters: You're right, that seems to be a German speciality (§69a, III UrhG).

Comment: Even that is arguable - the requirement that they have to be "Ergebnis der eigenen geistigen Schöpfung ihres Urhebers" (69a.3, result of the authors _own_ mental creation). A non-original work doesn't qualify for that.

Answer (score 6):

I *love* the GPL, but I have a simple rule for my own projects:

> The Code should be at least one order of magnitude longer than the license

If your code is just as long as the GPL, there probably is not that much stuff in it that an evil corporation could steal, even if you license it under the MIT X11 License.

As for the question of Public Domain: I live in Germany, where the *only* legal way to put something in the Public Domain is to commit suicide and wait 70 years (and hope that copyright protection time doesn't get increased between now and 2080). Which is a commitment I am not wanting to make :-) So, I don't really think about that.

Comment: There's plenty of useful code shorter than the GPL. DeCSS is a great example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeCSS

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter how trivial you believe the work to be; the question is whether it falls under copyright restriction or not. The default assumption is that **yes, any creative work falls under copyright** in just about any jurisdiction.

That's the same for a big program, a small script, an orchestral arrangement, or a sketch on a napkin.

In the absence of an explicit, effective grant of license, **all rights are reserved to the copyright holder**, which is you if you wrote it. So, like it or not, the burden of what freedoms to grant to others falls on your shoulders.

So, if you want recipients to have the essential software freedoms and know that others cannot legally block that, the only way to make that happen is to choose a free-software license and **grant it effectively**. The GNU GPL gives good instruction on how to apply it to a work.

Comment: Not the only way. Putting code in the Public Domain grants the same freedoms. GPL's forte is in ensuring the conservation of those freedoms as others modify your code.

Comment: Some more lax licenses, and a public domain grant, do grant those freedoms; but anyone can seal up such a work and block others from further improvements to that work. A copyleft license prevents that further restriction. I've now updated the answer to clarify this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you donate them to the public domain, you're giving up any rights to their ownership, and you're allowing anyone to use, modify, or sell them however they please.

If you release them under GPL, you can also allow anyone to use, modify, or sell them, but you're also explicitly requiring them to provide the same unrestricted use to all "downstream" users.  The spirit of GPL is that anyone who passes GPL software to anyone else must also provide the original rights and freedoms to use and further modify that software.

---

*Disclaimer:  This is my understanding of GPL, not legal advice.  Dammit, Jim, I'm an engineer, not a lawyer.*

Answer (score 2):

Scripts are programs, and if you order programming languages based on how abstract they are, bash would be high in the ordering.  It is valid to license bash code, and GPL is a fine choice.

Answer (score -1):

As long as your new license type does not violate the conditions of the license that comes along with the BASH, you are ok :-)

Comment: What? Bullshit. Code doesn't have to fall under the license of the interpreter, or every PHP app in existence would be open source.

Comment: Here is smth. that makes ceejayoz point without the Bullshit word: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#ReleaseUnderGPLAndNF